# How to remove « when I am in the current pagination and also » if I am in the last page of pagination using cakephp 3

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cakephp-3.0

[image]

I want to remove the << because I'm still in the root of pagination.

I have this index.ctp where I put the pagination

```
<div class="paginator">
        <ul class="pagination">
            <?= $this->Paginator->prev('< ' . __('previous')) ?>
            <?= $this->Paginator->numbers() ?>
            <?= $this->Paginator->next(__('next') . ' >') ?>
        </ul>
        <p><?= $this->Paginator->counter() ?></p>
</div>
```

This is my code in controllers index method

```
public function index()
{
  $website=  $this->set('websites', $this->paginate());
  $this->set('website', $website);
  $this->set('_serialize', ['website']);
}
```

This is also happens at the last pagination that I wanted to removed >>

[image]

Comment: CakePHPs paginator helper does not generate navigation controls with `«` or `»`, they must stem from somewhere else, maybe a plugin, maybe a script... unless you can show from where it stems, it's not really possible to give you a concrete answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can change the templates used by the paginator component

there are many ways (i.e. loading from a file as explained [**here**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/paginator.html#loading-templates-from-a-file))

or you can change on the the fly as explained [**here**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/helpers/paginator.html#changing-templates-at-run-time):

```
$this->Paginator->setTemplates([
    'nextDisabled' => '',
    'prevDisabled' => '',
]);
```

Comment: my point is how to removed this  << if Im not still clicking any page and also this >> if their is no data to display any more,

Comment: my code should do exactly this. It replaces the template cake uses for a disabled next or previous link with an empty string

Comment: I copied your code                                                  and this is the warning .................                                         
Warning (4096): Object of class Cake\View\Helper\PaginatorHelper could not be converted to string [APP/Template\Websites\index.ctp, line 64]

Comment: And what does line 64 of Template\Websites\index.ctp look like?

Comment: @GregSchmidt     this code                                                                     
<?= $this->Paginator->setTemplates([
    'nextDisabled' => '',
    'prevDisabled' => '',
]);?>

Comment: @arilia your code really did what  I wanted but their is warning.   Warning (4096): Object of class Cake\View\Helper\PaginatorHelper could not be converted to string [APP/Template\Websites\index.ctp, line 64]

Comment: Because you echoed the code (using <?= ) Simply use <?php instead